# If $b-c>1/2, b_n\to b$ and $c_n\to c$, there is $n$ such that $b_n,c_n \in (c-1/4,b+1/4)$ for all $n > N$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $b$ and $c$ are real numbers such that $b-c>1/2$. Let ${b_n}$ and ${c_n}$ converge to $b$ and $c$ respectively.

Show that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n>N$, both $b_n$ and $c_n$ belong to the open interval $(c-1/4,b+1/4)$.

Comment: Use the definition of convergence with $\varepsilon := 1/4$.

Comment: I think I was just overthinking the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your questions as informative as possible -- e.g. compare your original title and my revision. For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 2):

Since the sequences $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ converge to $b$ and $c$ respectively and so that since $(c-1/4,b+1/4)$ is a neighborhood of $b$ and $c$, so there exists naturals $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ such that for all $n>N_{1}$, $b_{n}$ belong to the $(c-1/4,b+1/4)$ and also for all $n>N_{2}$, $c_{n}$ belong to the $(c-1/4,b+1/4)$. Now get $N=Max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$, then the proof is done. Note that its not necessary that $b-c>1/2$. $b-c>-1/4$ is sufficient.

Comment: Indeed, $b-c>-\frac14$ is sufficient.

Comment: I think $b-c>-1/2$.

Comment: Why is $b-c>-1/2$ sufficient?

Comment: Since the length of interval $(c-1/4,b+1/4)$ must be positive.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Alisad, Hagen von Eitzen means the following: Let $b_n := -\dfrac1n$ and $c_n := \dfrac13 + \dfrac1n$. Then $b-c = -\dfrac13 > -\dfrac12$. But there are no $b_n$ or $c_n$ in $\left(c-\dfrac14, b+\dfrac14\right) = \left(\dfrac1{12}, \dfrac14\right)$.

Comment: Ohh yes, its true, its must be $b>c-1/4$ until $(c-1/4,b+1/4)$ be a neighborhood of $b$. Thanks